# Overlays - How to show an item from for x slides startin from the current overlay?

Tags: beamer, itemize, overlays

Using beamer's overlay I want to gradually show the items of an itemize environment. However some of the items are supposed to only show for say 3 slides. How do you do this?

In my understanding this should look something like

```
\only<.-3>{some text}
```

So starting from the current overlay (`.`) this should show up to the third following slide (`-3`).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are looking for `<.-+(2)>`. In detail this means:

- `.` the text starts to be visible on the current overlay
- `-` until
- `+(2)` the next to next overlay (the two overlays plus the frame where the text starts to be visible make then 3 overlays in total)

---

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\only<1>{1}
\only<.-+(2)>{some text}
\only<4>{4}
\only<5>{5}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```